# if statements in while loop JAVA

Tags: java

TRYING TO DO A MENU CHOICE,BUT DON'T KNOW WHY IT DOESN'T WORK.
I WANT TO GO BACK THE MENU WHEN I FINISH ADD ONE SCHOOL.
HOW DO I EXIT AND PRINT ALL INFORMATION FROM THE ARRAYLIST?

1. print out menu
2. user selects to create elementary school, college or high school student
3. prompts user for appropriate information
4. creates the appropriate object (calls constructor)
5. put object into ArrayList students
6. print out all students when user selects 4. from the menu
7. repeat until user selects “Exit” from menu

```
  System.out.println("Please select type of object to create:");
    System.out.println(
 "1) Elementry School\n2) High School\n3) College Student\n4)Print out all students\n5)Exit");
   int menuItem = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    while (menuItem != 5) {
        if (menuItem == 1) {
            System.out.println(
                    "You have selected to create a profile of a Elementary School Kid ..... ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the full name: ");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the Age: ");
            int age = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println(
                    "Please enter the name of the Elementry School: ");
            String eschool = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the City: ");
            String city = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the Teacher: ");
            String tname = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the Room No.: ");
            int rno = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            students.add(new ElementarySchoolStudent(name, age, city, eschool,
                    tname, rno));
        }

        else if(menuItem==2){
            System.out.println(
                    "You have selected to create a profile of a High School student ..... ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the full name: ");
            String n = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the Age: ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println(
                    "Please enter the name of the High school: ");
            String highsch = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the City: ");
            String add = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the counselor's name:");
            String counselor=in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter student’s gpa:");
            double g=in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the year of graduation:");
            int year=in.nextInt();
            students.add(new HighSchoolStudent(n,a,add,highsch,counselor,
                      year, g));
        }

        else if(menuItem==3){
            System.out.println(
                    "You have selected to create a profile of a college student ..... ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the full name: ");
            String n = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the Age: ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println(
                    "Please enter the name of the College: ");
            String college = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the City: ");
            String add = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the major of the student:");
            String mjr=in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter student's gpa:");
            double g=in.nextDouble();
            students.add(new CollegeStudent(n,a,add,college,mjr,g));
        }

        else if(menuItem==4){
            for(Student current : students)
            System.out.println(current.printStudent());
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: Please avoid using ALL-CAPS as that's the internet equivalent of SHOUTING.

Answer (score 1):

Put your menu inside your while loop so that it prints every time they enter a choice like this:

```
int menuItem = 0;
while (menuItem != 5) {
    System.out.println("Please select type of object to create:");
    System.out.println("1) Elementry School\n2) High School\n3) College Student\n4)Print out all students\n5)Exit");
    menuItem = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    if (menuItem == 1) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: and consider putting some code in methods.

Comment: Obviously there are a lot of other things in the code that should be cleaned up, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: The comment was a suggestion for the OP, the +1 was for you ;-)